# Allowing writes only if resources doesn't already exist on Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to set up Firebase security rules to allow uploading a file only if a file with the same name does not already exist. Ideally, I would like to support overriding a file when the contents of the new file are the same as the existing file.

I tried the following:

```
allow write: if !resource;
```

and

```
allow write: if !resource.size;
```

and

```
allow write: if request.resource.md5hash == resource.md5hash;
```

But neither seem to do the trick. All they do is simply disallow any uploads.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a combination of these:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<your-bucket>/o {
    match /path/to/file {
      // !resource allows the upload of a new file
      // hash comparison allows re-upload of the same file
      // note that property names are case-sensitive
      allow write: if !resource || request.resource.md5Hash == resource.md5Hash;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike! I tried your suggestion, but I still get HTTP 403 for every file that I try to upload once I apply these rules. It does let me upload when I use `allow write;`. I also occasionally get HTTP 500 with this message: "Failed to retrieve security rules."

Comment: !resource is giving me a problem too.

Comment: !resource is failing, bug resource==null works for me

Answer (score 2):

Use `resource == null` instead.

This is indeed missing from the docs, but [mentioned](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/) under the md5 note:

> Note: MD5 hash collisions are possible and could allow someone to overwrite a file, even if a rule like the above exists. Consider additional file validation or other rules to enforce immutability (e.g. `allow write: if resource == null;`)